# Removing other windows causes freeze/crash

Tags: python, window, pyside2

I want to have a main Window (class `MyMainWindow`), from which you can launch an undefined number of other Windows (class `MyWindow`), which you can use to get some information. Each of these other Windows is opened by pressing a button `btnWindow` in the main window and can be closed (with its (x)-button) when it is not needed any more.

All Windows are inherited from `QMainWindow`. So I have to keep a variable to point to them; otherwise they would be closed by the garbage collection. For this I use the list `self.children`. Since the main window stays open for hours and the user opens many windows and closes some of them, I want to keep track of the windows in use. For that I created an `eventFilter` which removes the windows to be closed from my list.
But unfortunately this causes the entire application to crash with a `SIGKILL` or a `SIGSEGV`.

```py
class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()                         # from QMainWindow
        self.setupUi(self)                         # from Ui_MainWindow
        self.children = []
        self.btnWindow.clicked.connect(self.onWindow)
        self.show()

    def onWindow(self):
        win = MyWindow()
        win.installEventFilter(self)
        self.children.append(win)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Close and obj in self.children:
            self.children.remove(obj)
        return False
```

So my questions are:

- Why does my application crash?
- How can I avoid the crash?
- Or is there a smarter way to keep track of the Windows in use and remove unused ones?

Comment: Just do `win = MyWindow(self); win.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)`. You don't need `children` (which shadows a built-in method). If you need to get a list of windows, use [QApplication.topLevelWindows()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#topLevelWindows) (or `mainwindow.findChildren(MyWindow)`). To close everything, use [QApplication.closeAllWindows()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#closeAllWindows).

Answer (score -1):

The [`QCloseEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcloseevent.html) is "sent to widgets that the user wants to close". So, not only the event is triggered when the window is *still* open, but it is also an event that can be *ignored*.

What happens in your case is that, by removing the *only* reference to that window, you're destroying it. But, at that point, a reference *still* exists: `eventFilter` has not returned yet, you're just removing the object from the list but since `obj` is within the scope of `eventFilter`, it's still a valid Qt object.

After that, you're returning `False`: when the event filter returns `False`, it means that the event *will* be handled: this is normally done by the `event()` of the object itself. Qt will actually send the `Close` event to the widget, and do *other* things after that. The problem is that at that point, `eventFilter()` has already returned, python has lost the *last* reference to the widget, and then it will *destroy* it.

So, Qt will be doing those "other" things, while in the meantime the object ceases to exist; this causes the program to freeze/crash because Qt is trying to access an object that has been removed from memory.

The simple solution would be to return `True` in the filter:

```py
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Close and obj in self.children:
            self.children.remove(obj)
            return True
        return False
```

This *should* ensure that the event won't be processed any more, so you don't risk any memory access issue.

Also note that some Qt classes already have an overridden `eventFilter()`, so it's always good practice to `return super().eventFilter(obj, event)` when the event is not handled or shouldn't be completely discarded (which doesn't mean it will or won't be ignored).

An important warning, though. Multiple event filters can be added to an object, and that could create a problem: if another filter was already set, you go back to square one, since the object has been destroyed.

A *better* solution is to not rely on the deletion by the garbage collector, but allow Qt to do it. In your case, it can be done by setting the `Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute on the window, and connect to the [`destroyed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal for the actual removal of the python reference:

```py
    def onWindow(self):
        def removeWin():
            if win in self.children:
                self.children.remove(win)
        win = MyWindow()
        win.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.children.append(win)
        win.destroyed.connect(removeWin)
        win.show()
```

An alternative solution, if you don't need a reference to those windows, is to set their parent.

For QMainWindow, you can do it just by adding the parent argument in the [constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#QMainWindow):

> QMainWindow sets the Qt::Window flag itself, and will hence always be created as a top-level widget.

So, the following is quite sufficient:

```py
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # ...

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def onWindow(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        win.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        win.show()
```

Or just do that in the constructor already:

```py
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        # ...

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def onWindow(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        win.show()
```

For any other QWidget, you either set the flag by yourself, or you manually set the parent using the [`QObject.setParent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setParent) function call, since the [`QWidget.setParent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent) override automatically resets all window flags (making the widget also a "physical" child, aka: shown *inside* the parent).

Supposing that `MyWindow` is just a QWidget subclass:

```py
    def onWindow(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        win.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        win.setWindowFlag(Qt.Window)
        win.show()

# or, alternatively:
    def onWindow(self):
        win = MyWindow() # <- no parent in the constructor
        QObject.setParent(win, self)
        win.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        win.show()
```

Obviously, as above, this can also be done in the `__init__` of the MyWindow class:

```py
    def onWindow(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        win.show()

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.Window)

# otherwise
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        QObject.setParent(self, parent)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
```

Note: it's normally good practice to *not* call `self.show()` in the `__init__` of a widget.